# Bootstrap - Move rows to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am new to Bootstrap, and would like to move my `box2` and `box3` divs to the bottom of the column on the right side of the page. I can't seem to work out how to do this without resorting to an empty row that is above `box2` and `box3`. Here is my current `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        .jumbotron {
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        h2 {
            margin: auto;
        }

        .box1 {
            min-height: 450px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }

        .box2 {
            min-height: 150px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }

        .box3 {
            min-height: 30px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body style="background:pink;">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="background:pink;">
              <h2>Lyrical</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="container-fluid">

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                      <div class="box1">FORM</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="box2">Description</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="box3">Credits</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way of doing this using the Bootstrap grid? 
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var bottom1 = $('.box1').outerHeight(true);
            var bottom2 = $('.right-sides-columns').outerHeight(true);
            var topheight = bottom1 - bottom2;
            $('.right-sides-columns').css("margin-top", topheight + "px");
        });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

        .jumbotron {
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        h2 {
            margin: auto;
        }

        .box1 {
            min-height: 450px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }

        .box2 {
            min-height: 150px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }

        .box3 {
            min-height: 30px;
            border-style: dotted;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body >
          <div class="jumbotron" >
              <h2>Lyrical</h2>
          </div>

          <div class="container-fluid">

              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                      <div class="box1">FORM</div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-3 right-sides-columns">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="box2">Description</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="box3">Credits</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works, but because the position is `absolute` it does not scale when the page is resized. Is there a way of doing the same thing, but keeping the re-sizing?

Comment: @ggordon i had updated my answer. add script to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific bootstrap answer, but a more general approach:

It is possible to push an element to the bottom of it's parent with  [flexbox's align-self](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-self/).

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 300px;
}
.flex-col {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
.flex-col--end {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col flex-col--end">
    <p>Dolor Sit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```